# Is Apache POI DataFormatter thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, apache-poi

is the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter` class of the Apache POI library thread-safe in order to share one instance between multiple threads?

In the FAQ (https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10224) they state:

> ..globally held object like global caches or other data structures are
>   guarded against multi threaded access..

, but does this also include the `DataFormatter` class?

Answer (score 1):

When reviewing the code of [DataFormatter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.java), it does not have any static modifiable members, but a number of normal members and no synchrnonization, so it will be thread-safe to use one instance in one thread at a time, but not safe to use one single DataFormatter in multiple threads at the same time.